# How to copy a char* into a char[][]

Tags: c, arrays, string

Before start, let me show you my code:

```
int     main(int argc, char *argv[])
{                  
  t_arbre       *node;
  char          str[3][1];

  &(*(str[0])) = strdup("1"); //lvalue required as left operand of assignment
  str[1] = strdup("2"); //incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[1]’ from type ‘char *’
  str[2] = strdup("3");
  if ((node = malloc(sizeof(t_arbre))) == NULL)
    {
      printf("Error: malloc in the main function failed\n");
      return (-1);
    }
  create_node(node, str);
  return (0);
}
```

So, as you can see, I'm currently working in C. And I'm trying to assign a (char*) to a (char[3][1]). Otherwise the compiler throw me for error:

> incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[1]’ from type ‘char *’

when I'm trying to assign by the following way:

```
str[2] = strdup("2");
```

I'm know that if I declare a string like this

```
char str[5];
```

and then try to assign it a string using for example strdup() function, it could trow me the same error. However in this case I know that I can "dereference" it like:

```
str[0]
```

Which will give me a (char) variable. And given I want it to store a string. I have to "transform" it into a (char*) by using the '&' charactere. Which will give me

```
&str[0]
```

In this case, it will work. because I have a pointer to the first character.
By doing so, I'll be able to copy a (char*) into a (char[]).

Otherwise, in the upper code I provide you, I want to copy a (char*) into a (char[3][1]) (Don't ask me why, it's a bit long to explain haha)
So as you can see, I tried my way to solve the error like

```
str[2] = strdup("2");
```

which throw me this error message

> incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[1]’ from type ‘char *’

And by this way

```
&(*(str[0])) = strdup("1"); //or &(*(str[0]))
```

which throw me this error message

> lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Does anyone can tell me how can I copy a (char*) into a (char[][]) ?
Or is it just imposible to do what I want to do ?
I don't speak english very well, hopeing I used the right term.

Thank you :)

Comment: A pointer is no array and an array is not a pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can't assign to things that aren't intended for assignment, that's what *"lvalue required as left operand of assignment"* is telling you, because you're taking the address of something with `&`, which is essentially just a value, not somewhere you can store something (e.g. a variable), and then trying to assign to it.
- A `char*` is not a `char[]`, that's what the incompatible types error is about.
- C arrays do not support assignment.
- Don't forget that in C, arrays start at index 0, so the last valid index in an array of length 3 is 2 (e.g. `arr[2]`), not 3.

Use [`strcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) instead to copy a string into an array:

```
char str[3][2]; // must allow space for the null terminator
strcpy(str[0], "1");
strcpy(str[1], "2");
strcpy(str[2], "3");
```

Or use an array of pointers and [`strdup()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup):

```
char *str[3];
str[0] = strdup("1");
...
```

If you do that, don't forget to free them when you're done, because `strdup()` allocates memory, e.g.

```
// free one pointer from the array:
free(str[0]);
// or if you have allocated to every value in the array:
size_t arr_len = sizeof(str) / sizeof(*str);
for (size_t n = 0; n < arr_len; ++n)
    free(str[n]);
```

Comment: Hello, in the first case, why have I to use strcpy instead of strdup ?
Because I read the man and the both function return a (char*)

Comment: @S7_0 In the first case you have an array of arrays, and you can't assign to an array – particularly not a pointer. (It seems you didn't read very carefully about what the functions do and what their return values are.)

Comment: @S7_0 `strcpy()` copies *into* it's first argument (which is a `char*`, but when you pass an array to a function it can decay to a pointer, which is why passing in the array works). Yes, it also returns a pointer, but we're not trying to assign that to an array (like you were before), so that's irrelevant. The most relevant info in the man pages is not what type the functions return, but what they actually *do*

Comment: Okay I think I understand, so the "main" difference is that strdup() ASSIGN variable instead of strcpy() which COPY into the variable and given I can't assign a pointer to an array, that's why strdup() doesn't work ? Isn't it ? If I'm right, I think I just didn't understand the subtlety..

Comment: @S7_0 That's the gist of it, yes. `strdup()` allocates memory for the string you give it, copies into the allocated memory, and returns a pointer to that memory, which you need to assign somewhere that can store a char* (which, as you note, can't be an array). Whereas `strcpy()` copies into the first argument you give it (which can be an array)

Answer (score 1):

`strdup` returns a pointer-to-a-char. If you want to store that pointer in an array, then you need an array of pointers, like this

```
char *str[3];           // an array of three pointer-to-char
str[0] = strdup("1");
str[1] = strdup("2");
str[2] = strdup("3");

for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    printf( "%s\n", str[i] );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy the entire string content you can use `strcpy`, however note that it copies null terminated strings. It is needed to have place for the last null symbol. So, the length of string arrays must be at least 2 (`char str[3][2]`) to copy strings like "1".